# Bagniamo vs Bagnamo: qual è meglio?

Tags: verbs, single-words

Salve,
Oggi leggevo un libro e a un tratto leggo:

Ci Bagnamo.

Io pensavo che si scrivesse Ci bagniamo (Pensavo ci fosse un eccezione o qualcosa del genere).

Potete spiegarmi il perché di questo?

Premetto che sono Italiano però mi è sorto questo dubbio.

Comment: Giusto per chiarire, *bagniamo* è la forma regolare, giacché i verbi di prima coniugazione hanno la prima persona plurale in *-iamo*. Ho controllato sul Devoto-Oli e non indica nessuna coniugazione particolare, per cui a meno di ulteriori prove io direi che *bagniamo* sia la forma corretta.

Comment: Anche la Treccani riporta la forma con la *i*: http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/bagnare/ mentre quest'altro sito (non so quanto affidabile) dice che si può accettare anche la forma senza *i*: http://www.sapere.it/sapere/dizionari/dizionari/Italiano/B/BA/bagnare.html

Comment: Il vero problema non è “bagnamo” (che pure è senz'altro sbagliato), ma “qual'é”, che concentra due errori in un colpo solo. Quali, Ronronner?

Comment: Non che servano altre conferme, ma anche lo Zingarelli riporta solo “bagniamo”.

Comment: Qual è** ! :) Attento!

Answer (score 7):

Non c'è motivo per scrivere *“bagnamo”. La radice del verbo è “bagn-”, la desinenza della I persona plurale del presente indicativo è “-iamo” (come “amiamo”), e quindi: “bagniamo”.

Per la II persona, regolarmente, “bagn-” + “-ate” (cf. “amate”) = “bagnate”.

Anche il congiuntivo, che per la I e II persona plurale può creare qualche dubbio, è regolare: “bagniamo” (come “amiamo”) e “bagniate” (come “amiate”).

Comment: Uhm. Grazie per la risposta corretta e dettagliata. E allora perché il libro scrive Bagnamo se è sbagliato!

Comment: Nessuno è perfetto, tutti commettiamo errori. Puoi dirci che libro è, @Ronronner?

Comment: Purtroppo sono in parecchi a omettere la “i“ della desinenza nei verbi in “gn-”; ci sono altri casi, come quello di *pasticciere* (come *salumiere*, *droghiere*) che troppi scrivono “pasticcere”.

Comment: Dag, "Io non ho paura" si chiama.

Comment: Perché allora scriviamo "compagna" e "compagnìa"? Qui la "i" serve perché reca l'accento! In "bagniamo" la "i" non è accentata; se lo fosse, dovremmo dire: "ba-gnì-a-mo". Quello di distinguere tra due diversi modi di pronunciare sarebbe l'unico motivo, a rigor di logica, per scrivere "bagniamo" con la "i", invece che, semplicemente, "bagnamo"!

Comment: @GuglielmoGranata: Le lingue naturali non funzionano sempre secondo la logica, Guglielmo. Ci sono vari altri motivi (storici, etimologici, accidentali...) per cui si portano dietro stranezze e incoerenze.

Comment: È l'uso concreto della lingua da parte degli effettivi utenti e/o fruitori che ne fa la storia. Non facciamoci "mummificare" la lingua scritta dalle esigenze di codifica dettate dal bisogno di stare in pace con la... regola. L'analogia, se non la logica, ha i suoi diritti di cittadinanza. Ovviamente : "Adelante,  Pedro, con juicio!".

Answer (score 3):

Riporto citando testualmente dal sito della Crusca dall'articolo [Sul digramma *gn* e sulla presenza della *i* in forme verbali come *guadagniamo*](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/digramma-gn-presenza-forme-verbali-guadagnia) cui rimando per chi fosse interessato ad approfondire:

> ...se la regola prescrive che la i non compaia, come si spiegano forme come bagniamo in luogo di bagnamo? [..*omissis*...] Per il caso in esame, **la desinenza della prima persona dell'indicativo presente plurale di tutti i verbi è -iamo**: quindi, come si ha *am-iamo*, così si ha *sogn-iamo*, *bagn-iamo* ecc.: omettere quella i significa "tagliare" una parte del morfema flessivo per quel tempo, modo e persona.
>
> Spiegato il motivo della presenza della *i* va detto che la norma, oggigiorno, è relativamente elastica in merito. Patota, in appendice alla grammatica di Serianni, scrive: «Nei verbi con tema uscente in *-gn* (come [...] *bagnare, sognare, vergognarsi, regnare* ecc.) alla quarta persona di indicativo e congiuntivo e alla quinta del congiuntivo (*bagniate / bagnate*) la *i* della desinenza viene assorbita [nella pronuncia] dal suono palatale precedente. Può essere opportuno mantenerla graficamente per ribadire la solidarietà di quelle forme con tutti gli altri indicativi e congiuntivi in -iamo, nei quali la i ha conservato la sua piena riconoscibilità fonetica (amiamo [a'mjamo]) o è indispensabile come segno diacritico (leggiamo [led'dZamo]). **La norma grammaticale è comunque tollerante in proposito, sicché forme come *bagnamo* o *bagnate* non potrebbero essere considerati errori**».

A conforto della tolleranza, si veda [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/grammatica/grammatica_261.html).

Pertanto, sarei dell'idea di non dare troppo addosso al povero Ammaniti per il *bagnamo* nel romanzo *Io non ho paura*, perché come sintetizza Elisabetta Perini nel suo libro "Scrivere bene (o quasi)": *«La risposta corretta è: bagniamo. (**Ma bagnamo, senza la i, non è più un errore**)».*